# How to access Owner of Parent Record of FeedItem

Tags: apex, feeditem, casefeed

I am trying to send emails to the owners of cases when people post to the case feed. Traversing up through parent records seems to have some strange functionality:

```
for(FeedItem FI : FeedItems ) {
    String Name = FI.Parent.Name;  //works just fine
    ID id = FI.Parent.OwnerID;  //returns "Variable does not exist: OwnerID"             
}
```

So I can go up one level to the name of the parent record, but not up another level to the owner of that record. I imagine some further querying is necessary, but I am stuck on how to do it without creating a query within a for loop (I know the query below is not in the for loop, I took it out, but trying to figure out where to go from here. Thoughts?

```
for(FeedItem FI : FeedItems ) {
    mapCaseIDtoFeedItem.put(FI.ParentID,FI);               
}

for(Case C : [SELECT OwnerID FROM Case WHERE Id IN: mapCaseIDtoFeedItem.keySet()]){
    ...something here?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just came up with this, happy to hear if there are more efficient ways!

```
        Set<ID> CaseIDs = new Set<ID>();
        Map<ID,ID> mapCaseIDtoOwnerID = new Map<ID,ID>();     

        for(FeedItem FI : FeedItems) {
            CaseIDs.add(FI.ParentID);
        }

        for(Case C : [SELECT ID from Case WHERE ID IN :CaseIDs]) {
            mapCaseIDtoOwnerID.put(C.ID,C.OwnerID);               
        }

        for(FeedItem FI : FeedItems) {
            mapCaseIDtoOwnerID.get(FI.ParentId)
```

Comment: this will break if `FI.ParentId` is not an ID for `Case.SObjectType`

Comment: Thanks, yes, it should be wrapped in a condition that specifies the parent ID starts with 500

Comment: parentId.getSobjectType() == Case.SobjectType

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed solution appears quite correct, and the formulation you have does *not* qualify as a query in a `for` loop. Iterating over a query result like that is a common and expected pattern that does not come with bulkification concerns.

The reason you're encountering this error is that the `ParentId` relationship is polymorphic. (So too, in fact, is the `OwnerId` relationship). You can only access a tiny subset of fields when you traverse a polymorphic relationship, such as `Name` and `Type`, because you don't know what kind of record is on the far side of the relationship. (Circumstances where this doesn't apply are described in [the SOQL reference for polymorphic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys.htm).

Comment: couldn't OP use the SELECT TYPEOF ... (avail V46) to get Case's OwnerId?

Comment: David Reed - thanks, but what I included was not a solution at all! See the "something here"?

Comment: Thanks cropredy - what do you mean by "couldn't OP use the SELECT TYPEOF"?

Comment: @number41 - see [SOQL TYPEOF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm?search_text=typeof) for accessing polymorphic lookup relationship fields